# Как работают state в React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Есть пример кода:

```
class Conditioner extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {temperature: 0};

      // Привязка необходима, чтобы сделать this доступным в коллбэке
      this.onIncrease = this.onIncrease.bind(this);
      this.onDecrease = this.onDecrease.bind(this);
    }

    onIncrease(){
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        temperature: prevState.temperature + 1
      }))
    }

    onDecrease(){
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        temperature: prevState.temperature - 1
      }))
    }

    render() {
      return (<p>
          <h2>Текущая температура: {this.state.temperature}</h2>
          <button onClick={this.onDecrease}>-</button>
          <button onClick={this.onIncrease}>+</button>
        </p>);
    }
  }
```

В методах `onIncrease` и `onDecrease` есть место:

```
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    temperature: prevState.temperature + 1
  }))
```

Понятно что `prevState` это параметр который мы посылаем в функцию `onClick={this.onDecrease}`, но где вызов этой функции с данным параметром? И каким образом вместо `this.state.temperature`, у нас получилось `prevState.temperature`? Где и как определена связь между  `this.state` и `prevState`? Они как будто синонимы... Но как так получилось?

Объясните пожалуйста как это работает. Спасибо.

Comment: *но где вызов этой функции с данным параметром?* -- очевидно, если вы сами его не совершаете, но он происходит, то это происходит внутри библиотек, которые вы используете. В этом контексте кандидат всего один, React.

Comment: @D-side логично. А имя prevState может быть любым как я понимаю. Правильно?

Comment: Оно объявляется в сигнатуре функции, используется только внутри неё. По всей видимости, да.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`prevState` = `this.state` в момент вызова `this.setState`.

Разберем по шагах:

1. По клику на `<button>` срабатывает переданная в `onClick` функция `this.onIncrease`.
2. После вызова `this.onIncrease` вызывает метод `this.setState`.

У `setState` может быть 2 аргумента:

`this.setState((prevState, props) => ({ temp: prevState.temp + 1 }), callback)`,

где `(prevState, props) => ({ temp: prevState.temp + 1 })` - первый аргумент - функция, которая возвращает новое значения `this.state`, а `callback` - второй аргумент - функция, которая срабатывает после завершения обновления `this.state` (**не сразу**).

Ми получаем `(prevState, props)` от React автоматически в момент вызова `setState`.

> Где и как определена связь между this.state и prevState?

Связь между ними обеспечивает сам React без нашего вмешательства.

Подробней можно прочитать в [документации](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)